# MongoserverError: bad auth: authentication failed problem

Tags: mongodb, authentication, visual-studio-code, mongodb-atlas

I correctly use the username and password in the url of vs code for my server side but in the cmd i find the error of mongodb authentication fail. why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the uri again and give the username and password again. sometimes connection fails. that's why it happens. hope problem will be solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).